# What is a Package, Stack, Repository?

Tags: ros, stack, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Could someone please tell me the difference between a Package, Stack and a Repository in the context of ROS?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10254/what-is-a-package,-stack,-repository?/) by [kissandra79](https://answers.ros.org/users/648/kissandra79/) on ROS Answers with karma: 53 on 2011-06-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

A repository is usually a collection of stacks, that are a collections of packages.

Usually a repository contains all stacks supplied by one organization.
Stacks contain packages that are thematically similar.

Further reading: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Packages

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2011-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kissandra79](https://answers.ros.org/users/648/kissandra79/) on 2011-06-14**:
Thank you very much. Clear, concise and to the point

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

dornhege's answer is pretty good, but to relate it to purpose:

Packages are the basic unit of creating/building ROS code.  They are the lowest-level building block of what you can build in ROS. They may contain a particular algorithm, library, set of messages, or some other basic building block.

Stacks are the basic unit of releasing ROS code.  They usually collect together thematically similar Packages.  Ultimately Stacks are meant to bundle together code that is developed together and is mutually interdependent.  For example, the navigation stack consists of several planner packages, a high-level ROS node, a localization package, and obstacle data structures.

Repositories are just code repositories, i.e. and svn/hg/git/bzr repository.  These code repositories are usually associated with organizations or a community of developers.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-06-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 9